# Flutter desktop app for Linux - but Linux server not running desktop

Tags: linux, flutter, server, desktop-application

Question:  Is there any way to provide a terminal connection with a canvas to a Flutter app being hosted on a non-gui Linux server?

Context:  We have a lot of character-based tools running on (CentOS) Linux server.  It would be great to write them (or a wrapper around them) as GUI apps using Flutter.  I don't need full window management, just things like GUI components, mouse text selection, cut-n-paste, drag-n-drop, SDI design UI.

Is there any way to accomplish that **without installing desktop software on the server**?  I know there's a Raspberry Pi setup for flutter apps on Linux WITHOUT installing desktop.  Would anything like that work?